# How to make an Android app mulithreaded

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've created an app that was running just fine until recently... but now it's crashing with errors stating "Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

From what I've gathered I need to implement multi threading in the application but I'm curious as to the easiest, fastest and most efficient way of doing so!

(I've included my source code below)

---

### AppActivity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

// add button listener
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        context);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Settings Menu");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Link or Delete?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Link",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        //start new activity

        Intent intentApp2Activity = new Intent(AppActivity.this, App2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intentApp2Activity);

        // if this button is clicked, close
        // current activity
        AppActivity.this.finish();
    }
  })
        .setNegativeButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
}}
```

---

### App2Activity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
}

}
```

---

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1"     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="NFC Linking     Manager" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Linksys Router (Home)" android:onClick="onPopupBtClick" />
<Button android:id="@+id/Button2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Netgear Router (Office)" />
<Button android:id="@+id/Button3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Cisco Router (Office)" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="User Settings:" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Data Limit" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="10MB" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <TextView android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Unlimited Data" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Bandwidth Limit" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="10kbs" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <TextView android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="WiFi Time Limit" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Blocked Sites - [ex: www.xxx.com]" android:ems="10" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mkyong.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".App2Activity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Don't post your whole app and ask us how to fix it. Think about the logic yourself and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

Multithreading is not a simple tool you plug in.  You just asked us to architect/design your application.  Start by reading *Java: Concurrency in Practice.*

Comment: I just watched a tutorial on multithreading... and I'm about to watch another - I was just wondering if anyone could offer any suggestions.

Comment: @AmaniSwann Unfortunately my answer is correct.  You need to actually learn this topic thoroughly as concurrency bugs are incredibly insidious - your program will work fine in testing then get mysterious undefined behavior in production that you will be unable to reproduce in test.  This is not a "tips and tricks" site and you cannot learn this topic over tips and tricks.

Comment: @AmaniSwann you should learn asynctask  then implement in your code.first you have to learn and work out in your own interest. android guru's just suggest a tips and tricks to simplify your problem. just learn multi thread concept and implement simple program and then analyse how to use multi thread concept in your code. Best of luck:)

Answer (score 1):

Android provides the AsyncTask class for simple tasks that can be run in a thread

Comment: True, but just have to diligently point out that running in an AsyncTask does not guarantee threadsafety.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to thread something away is the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
     //Dosomething here
}).start();
```

this is however VERY basic, and leaves you with no control over your thread